# Getting error when trying to send AT command on Samsung S20

Tags: serial-port, at-command, modem, samsung

Sending AT command to my Samsung S20 to find out the modem version. In response I get `+CME Error:PACM(CP),UNREGISTED`. The commands are sent via Realterm. I also sometimes get a `+CME Error:PACM(AP),NOT_ALLOWED_CRO` response. How to find a detailed error description?

My goal is to find commands to communicate with eSIM. To do it I want to find a specs for the modem.

The full interaction process:

```
AT
OK

ATI
CME Error:PACM(CP),UNREGISTED
```

Tried to send commands via Realterm and SimCOM. I also listened to the COM port through the Serial Port Monitor. All commands are sent and responses are read.